# Bursting with... broad-mindedness

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

**If**

- 2010THADFA + 2014IFTH = WHAT IF?,
- 1996RE + 2012NE = SANTA FE,
- 1987INTHWO + 2002HA = IT TAKES TWO,
- 1975THWI + 1994BEANTHBE = HOME,

**then** (in increasing order of difficulty)

- 2007XA + 2009NETONO = ?,
- 1966CA + ? = ? (two solutions)
- 2015HA + ? + ? = ?

Super extra bonus:

- 2015AL + ? + ? + ? = ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is:

> I'M ALIVE

The second is

> 2014IFTH, giving WHAT WOULD YOU DO?
>   1970GE, giving SO WHAT?

The third is

> 1970LOLAKIGE and 2015SORO, giving RIGHT HAND MAN

Super extra bonus

> 2012GHTHMU, 1983BA, and 1972PI, giving WITH YOU

And here's the key:

> The equations are in the form of [four-digit year of Broadway* debut][first two letters of each of the words in the title] + same = SONG TITLE COMMON TO BOTH MUSICALS
>
>  e.g.,
>
>   2010 ***TH***E **AD**DAMS **FA**MILY + 2014 ***IF***/**TH**EN = WHAT IF?
>   1996 ***RE***NT + 2012 ***NE***WSIES = SANTA FE
>   1987 ***IN***TO **TH**E **WO**ODS + 2002 ***HA***IRSPRAY = IT TAKES TWO
>   1975 ***TH***E **WI**Z + 1994 ***BE***AUTY **AN**D **TH**E **BE**AST = HOME
>
>   2007 ***XA***NADU + 2009 ***NE***XT **TO** **NO**RMAL = I'M ALIVE
>   1966 ***CA***BARET + 2014 ***IF***/**TH**EN = WHAT WOULD YOU DO?
>   1966 ***CA***BARET + 1970 ***GE***ORGY = SO WHAT?
>   2015 ***HA***MILTON + 1970 ***LO***VELY **LA**DIES, **KI**ND **GE**NTLEMEN + 2015 ***SO***METHING **RO**TTEN = RIGHT HAND MAN
>
>   2015 ***AL***LEGIANCE + 2012 ***GH***OST **TH**E **MU**SICAL + 1983 ***BA***BY + 1972 ***PI***PPIN = WITH YOU
>
>  * *Ho ho! "Broad"-mindedness!*

As hinted to in the comments:

> Adding the word "THE" to a song from Cabaret gives us 1991 ***MI***SS **SA**IGON (THE TELEPHONE SONG)

Comment: Your first one is correct as well as _one_ of your second ones. Keep it up!

Comment: @Will OK, so to clarify - for the second one, when you say "two solutions", do you mean what I've done (i.e., give two "operands" and a solution for each), or a single "operand" yields two solutions?

Comment: Two different "addends" yield two different "sums."

Comment: You won't need to change/add any words, though you can find a third solution by adding "THE" to the beginning of one to match the other.

Comment: @Will then we'd be talking about 1991MISA

Comment: Could you identify the musicals in all the answers, please? I'm curious :)

Comment: @AZGreenTea I fleshed it out a bit in the bottom chunk of spoilertext, take a look